# Create PDImageXObject from InputStream

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to create [PDImageXObject](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html) from huge JPEG file *(20 000 x 20 000 pixels [24-bit color])*

Methods:

- [PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromByteArray-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-byte:A-java.lang.String-),
- [PDImageXObject.createFromFile(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFile-java.lang.String-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-)
- [PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFileByContent-java.io.File-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-)
- [PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFileByExtension-java.io.File-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-)

Creates `ByteArrayInputStream` object and allocates more than 1GB of RAM, which causes Exception

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
```

Exception in line:

```java
buf = new byte[size];
```

I know that the number of bytes for image processing = 
`W * H * color bits \ 9`;

That's why I don't want to load all file bytes at a time.

I've tried to set maximum heap size to `-Xmx2G` but it isn't enough.
I've also tried to use methods
[LosslessFactory.createFromImage(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/LosslessFactory.html#createFromImage-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-),
[JPEGFactory.createFromImage(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/JPEGFactory.html#createFromImage-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-) , but they has the same problem

Is there any way to create PDImageXObject from InputStream (f.e. from FileInputStream), without creating BufferedImage or byte arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

Spawn a thread to run a command-line utility (e.g. [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)) which will reduce the size of the image to what will fit within the space on the page which you have allotted for the image.

Then load that reduced-size image.

You don't need a higher resolution image or bigger-size image than what will fit on the page.

There are also several java libraries which will do that for you without the considerable process-spawning overhead.  See this Baeldung article for a quick rundown on the more popular ways to do so: [Baeldung: How can I resize an image using Java?](https://www.baeldung.com/java-resize-image).

Of course, you'll have to experiment to see how much main memory each library uses.

Comment: So the reply to my question is just that I can't have an input stream directly from the library and I need to forcibly pass through a BufferedImage or whatever else OR use another tool to extract the image. That's a bit unfortunate.